# why there is no attribute like 'GetNAClassNames' in my arcpy

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, arcgis-10.3

I want to do a network analysis, when I want to load a layer as a barrier using arcpy.na.GetNAClassNames, the message is like this:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GetNAClassNames'
why?my current version is arcGIS 10.3

Comment: Sounds like you are importing a module instead of a class. Can you provide some example code so we can reproduce your error?

Comment: Humor me, what does `arcpy.GetInstallInfo()['Version']` return?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm that is strange.  Does this return True?

```
>>> import arcpy
>>> 'GetNAClassNames' in dir(arcpy.na)
True
```

I don't know how it could be missing, perhaps something could have gone wrong during your install?